# About fibers of a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a surjective morphism bewteen algebraic varieties , does the locus of non-reduced fibers form a closed subset of $Y$?

If the condition is not good enough, one may add conditions on smoothness, projectiveness or flatness.I am not clear what are suitable for this.

Thanks for any comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locus of non-reduced fibres is closed, and the locus of reduced fibres is open.  (If one is not working over an alg. closed field, or is working in some more general scheme-theoretic context, then it might be better to say *geometrically reduced* here, and to impose some finiteness condition on the morphism, something which will be automatic for maps between varieties.)

---

Actually, probably what I should have said is that the locus of points where
the fibre is geometrically reduced is constructible.  If the map is further
flat, then it is open.  (See the remark at the end of section 1 in [this write-up](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/geofibersnov2710.pdf) by Ravi Vakil,
and also [this discussion](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0574) in the stacks project.)

Comment: I am sorry I would mean nonreduced... So could you explain why the locus with non-reduced fiber form a closed subset? Thanks!

Comment: @mqx: I edited in a correction and more details.